# Add facet & value programmatically with VisualSearch.js

Tags: javascript

I'm using VisualSearch.js. Works great out of the box but my interface has a list of links. When user clicks on one of these it will add a facet & value (i.e. tag:cats) to the search box and trigger the search taking into account any other search inputs that are already there.

I don't see a clear way to do this from the source code - Am I missing something? http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - using the addFacet method from visualSearch.js - like this:

//add a tag filter
visualSearch.searchBox.addFacet('tag', tag.name, 0);

Comment: Can you clarify? I'm not sure what object you're referencing with the tag.name –– no matter what I pass to this function, I receive an error --> Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You should find the addFacet function in search_box.js like below:

```
addFacet : function(category, initialQuery, position) {
```

"category" will be facet's name, "initialQuery" will be the pre-populate value.